# How to build bar plot with group by day/hour interval?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have this dataset:

```
                              name                         date
0                 ramos-vinolas-sao-paulo-2017-final 2017-03-05 22:50:00
1        sao-paulo-2017-doubles-final-sa-dutra-silva 2017-03-05 19:29:00
2                       querrey-acapulco-2017-trophy 2017-03-05 06:08:00
3          soares-murray-acapulco-2017-doubles-final 2017-03-05 02:48:00
4                     cuevas-sao-paulo-2017-saturday 2017-03-04 21:54:00
5              dubai-2017-doubles-final-rojer-tecau2 2017-03-04 18:23:00
```

I'd like to build bar plot with amount of news by day/hour. Something like

```
  count    date
    4   2017-03-05  
    2   2017-03-04
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), for ploting [`bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
#if necessary convert to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

print (df.date.dt.date.value_counts())
2017-03-05    4
2017-03-04    2
Name: date, dtype: int64

df.date.dt.date.value_counts().plot.bar()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Is the any way to add order? Sort them by date and add dates that are not in dataset. For example if i want to see amount of news since 2017-03-01.

Comment: I think the best is create new question with sample and desired output, because I am not sure if understand.  But it seems you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is using the pandas function [`hist()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html):

```
df["date"].hist()
```